# Does Visual Studio Test (VSTest) have an equivalent of `CPPUNIT_ASSERT_ASSERTION_FAIL`?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing

In my test code, I'd like to avoid simple errors leading to false negatives (that is, tests passing falsely), so I usually add one test case that is supposed to fail due to ever so slight mismatches between the output and the baseline. But I don't want to give testers the impression that anything went wrong. I could name this test "..._ExpectedFailure", but automated testers probably won't understand that suffix.

How am I supposed to do this in VSTest? I have seen that with CppUnit, I could use `CPPUNIT_ASSERT_ASSERTION_FAIL`, into which I can simply wrap a complete (failing) test case. Is there something equivalent in VSTest?

Comment: I suggest you read this [issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options?view=vs-2022), here are some command-line options for your reference

Comment: @YujianYao-MSFT this somehow does not answer my question, or does it?